# System interrupts 49% cpu usage

Tags: windows, cpu-usage

how can I check if its a software or hardware problem? I've tried to unplug all USB ports (mouse, keyboard) but nothing happened. does a bad battery can cause this problem ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The answers on the duplicate question should give you pointers on how to diagnose what is causing your problem.